# 415 unsuported media type

Tags: angular, webapi

Issue: unsuported media type 415

Context: Well I tried to register data via post method, the object that I sent has three properties export class Livre {titre:string,prix:Number,taille:Number}

and this is the client side

```
postEntity<T>():Observable<T>{
    this.initUrl();
    let header:HttpHeaders =
     new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
     .set('accept','application/json');
    return this._http.post<T>(this.basicUrl + 'add/',{headers:header}, this.entity)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));;
  }
```

This above method is defined with  generic service which will be inhertied later on and its inhertience is injected within the component constrcutor

From the server side here is the called method

```
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("add")]
        public IActionResult Add([FromBody]Livre Livre)
        {
            _model.Add(Livre);
            return Ok(_model);
        }
```

When I debug every thing works like a charm I can step though all over the code client sie to server side however that added data members are  null with that error unsuported media type 415

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters to the `post` method are in the wrong order, switch the body with the options:

`return this._http.post<T>(this.basicUrl + 'add/', this.entity,{headers:header}) ...`

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rfgmm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)